# Wordpress footer widget settings

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hello this is the link of my website

http://webienz.com/

In footer i want to set 3rd widget as contact info like this
**Contact info**
Contact Info UK (with flag of UK)
phone
email
address

Contact Info Pakistan (with flag of Pakistan)
phone
email
address

I have purchased theme and i have done some some editing boc.widgets.php but one contact info displaying at a time not both UK and Pakistan here is the original code of contact widget

```
* Contact Info Widget

class contact_info_widget extends WP_Widget {

function contact_info_widget()
{
$widget_ops = array('classname' => 'contact_info', 'description' => '');
$this->WP_Widget('contact_info-widget', 'Terra: Contact Info', $widget_ops);
}

function widget($args, $instance)
{

extract($args);
$title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

echo $before_widget;

if($title) {
echo $before_title.$title.$after_title;
}
?>
<?php if($instance['phone']): ?>
<div class="icon_phone"><?php echo $instance['phone']; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($instance['email']): ?>
<div class="icon_mail"><?php echo $instance['email']; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($instance['address']): ?>
<div class="icon_loc"><?php echo $instance['address']; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear h10"></div>

    <?php
    echo $after_widget;
}

function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
{
    $instance = $old_instance;

    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['address'] = $new_instance['address'];
    $instance['phone'] = $new_instance['phone'];
    $instance['fax'] = $new_instance['fax'];
    $instance['email'] = $new_instance['email'];
    $instance['web'] = $new_instance['web'];

    return $instance;
}

function form($instance)
{
    $defaults = array('title' => 'Contact Info');
    $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults); ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone'); ?>">Phone:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('phone'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['phone']; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email'); ?>">Email:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('email'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['email']; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>">Address:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('address'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['address']; ?>" />
    </p>


<?php
}
}
```

**and this is the code i have edited**

/**
 * Contact Info Widget
 */

```
class contact_info_widget extends WP_Widget {

function contact_info_widget()
{
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'contact_info', 'description' => '');
    $this->WP_Widget('contact_info-widget', 'Terra: Contact Info', $widget_ops);
}

function widget($args, $instance)
{
    extract($args);
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

    echo $before_widget;

    if($title) {
        echo $before_title.$title.$after_title;
    }
    ?>
    <?php if($instance['phone']): ?>
    <div class="icon_phone"><?php echo $instance['phone']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php if($instance['phone2']): ?>
    <div class="icon_phone"><?php echo $instance['phone2']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if($instance['email']): ?>
    <div class="icon_mail"><?php echo $instance['email']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>


<?php if($instance['email2']): ?>
    <div class="icon_mail"><?php echo $instance['email2']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if($instance['address']): ?>
    <div class="icon_loc"><?php echo $instance['address']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php if($instance['address2']): ?>
    <div class="icon_loc"><?php echo $instance['address2']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear h10"></div>

    <?php
    echo $after_widget;
}

function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
{
    $instance = $old_instance;

    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['address'] = $new_instance['address'];
            $instance['address2'] = $new_instance['address2'];
    $instance['phone'] = $new_instance['phone'];
            $instance['phone2'] = $new_instance['phone2'];
    $instance['fax'] = $new_instance['fax'];
    $instance['email'] = $new_instance['email'];
            $instance['email2'] = $new_instance['email2'];
    $instance['web'] = $new_instance['web'];

    return $instance;
}

function form($instance)
{
    $defaults = array('title' => 'Contact Info');
    $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults); ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title:</label>


<input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone'); ?>">Phone:</label>


<input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('phone'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['phone']; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email'); ?>">Email:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('email'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['email']; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>">Address:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('address'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['address']; ?>" />
    </p>
```

get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title:
            get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="" />

```
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone2'); ?>">Phone:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('phone2'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['phone2']; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email2'); ?>">Email:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('email2'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['email2']; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address2'); ?>">Address:</label>
        <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('address2'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['address2']; ?>" />
    </p>
<?php
}


}
```

Please help me out in this code that how i can get desired output in footer i dont have too much know how about php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are having trouble with duplicating the fields, then just try a text widget
as a replacement